# How to run kubernetes workload on another NIC?

Tags: kubernetes, network

We have 2 NIC's in our k8s nodes and now, My team has a requirement to run the workload on other NIC. Note: This is a fresh installation of cluster. So, Is it possible to run workload on other NIC?

I am not sure if this is really possible. If yes, how? I checked the official k8s documents but did not find any reference to it.

In my understanding, I need to install the k8s cluster with pod-cidr/cluster-cidr with another NIC IP. I am a newbie to k8s. So, Can someone please help to clarify or give some hints? Thanks in advance.